# CSS - Curved Corner after using border-left and border-bottom

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have used border-left and border-bottom to create a sort of one sided parallelogram shape for a bootstrap navbar, but I also need the right side to be curved while keeping the left side transparent.

Current outcome:

[image: Current outcome]

Wanted outcome:

[image: Wanted Outcome]

I have tried using border-top-right-radius but nothing happens:

```
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    border-bottom: 50px solid rgba(58, 162, 178, 0.5);
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;

    /* Tried */
    border-top-right-radius: 2em;
}
```

I have made a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6qfbhxty/

Comment: Your jsfiddle shows your Wanted outcome

Comment: Only as an image I created in paint.

Comment: the outcome depends on the browser, you need to add what you have with `-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 2em;
        -moz-border-radius-topright: 2em;
        border-top-right-radius: 2em;` to account for webkit browsers and firefox

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your example the blue bar is the bottom border. It won't work because you can't give the "end" of the border a curved look.

You could try to apply the blue color as background and use `:before` to create the triangle.

Please notice to apply the same color to the background and the border!

```css
body {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/800/800/abstract");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.navbar {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0px 0px 20px 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: rgba(58, 162, 178, 0.8);
  border-top-right-radius: 16px 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 16px 25px;
}
.navbar:before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: -50px;
  border: solid transparent;
  border-width: 0 0 50px 50px;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(58, 162, 178, 0.8);
}
h3 {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar" style="width:75%;">
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse"></div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <h3>Wanted outcome (shape wise):</h3>

  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnFO2.png">
```

edited the snippet for better code

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css for the curved right side:

```
    border-top-right-radius: 2em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2em;
```

Comment: This only curved the bottom-right side, not the top

Comment: It should be border-top-right-radius: 2em 2em; and border-bottom-right-radius: 2em 2em;